# Импорт записей в произвольный тип записей

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как можно импортировать новые записи в произвольный тип данных?
По умолчанию wordpress импортирует в тип записей по умолчанию - пост.
Есть ли плагин какой-то для этого?

Comment: откуда импорт производится?

Comment: может быть из разных источников. Пусть будет xlsx

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/ импорт вордпрессовский,
https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/ более продвинутый

Comment: @Eduard Misk, я что-то не нашёл в этих плагинах, как нужно импортировать в произвольный тип данных.
Допустим есть новый тип записей - newtype. Как сделать импорт из xlsx-файла в этот новый тип?

Comment: отписал в ответах

Answer (score 0):

Не импортировал из такого формата, но судя по описанию "Really Simple CSV Importer" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/) там есть примеры в CSV формате. Видимо придется сначала экспортировать в csv и потом оформить согласно структуре примера.
А сам выбор типа записи производится непосредственно в колонке "post_type".